# Image/file upload in php

Tags: php, file-handling

```
 <?php

if (isset($_FILES['image']))
    {
    $filename = $_FILES['image']['name'];
    $filetmp = $_FILES['image']['tmp_name'];
    move_uploaded_file($filetmp, "uploads/" . $filename);
    echo "Upload Successfully!";
    }

?>

<form method="post" action="" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="file" name="image">
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

In the html part, the form has three parts (method, action and enctype). What will I write in the 'action' part?

Comment: You can leave it blank if you're going to process the upload in the same page (as it seems to be the case). You use the `action` parameter when you're sending the data to another page / script.

Comment: What is the $_SERVER["PHP_SELF"] variable?

Comment: From the PHP manual: [PHP_SELF](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php#refsect1-reserved.variables.server-indices) returns "the filename of the currently executing script, relative to the document root."

Comment: https://php.net/manual/reserved.variables.server.php
Please, try to search for something, before asking.

Comment: Just a note: Usually you code something then run it to see if it works. Only if it doesn't work do you ask here for help.

Comment: Is there something that is not working?

Answer (score 0):

```
 <?php

   if (isset($_POST['uploadimage']))
     {
     $filename = $_FILES['image']['name'];
     $filetmp = $_FILES['image']['tmp_name'];
     move_uploaded_file($filetmp, "uploads/" . $filename);
     echo "Upload Successfully!";
     }

 ?>

 <form method="post" action="thisfilename.php" enctype="multipart/form-data">
     <input type="file" name="image">
     <input type="submit" value="Submit" id="uploadimage">
 </form>
```

you can use this type. thisfilename.php , your php file's name.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a script you can use to upload a file.

```
$target_dir = "your directory";
$target_file = $target_dir . basename($_FILES["file"]["name"]);
$target_file = preg_replace('/\s+/', '_', $target_file);
$uploadOk = 1;
$FileType = strtolower(pathinfo($target_file,PATHINFO_EXTENSION));
// Check if image file is a actual image or fake image

// Check if file already exists
if (file_exists($target_file)) {
    $uploadOk = 0;
}
// Check file size
if ($_FILES["file"]["size"] > 5000000) {
    $uploadOk = 0;
}
// Allow certain file formats
if($FileType == "wav" OR $FileType == "jpg" OR $FileType == "png" ) {
    $uploadOk = 0;
}

// Check if $uploadOk is set to 0 by an error
if ($uploadOk == 0) {
    echo "Sorry, your file was not uploaded.";
// if everything is ok, try to upload file
} else {
    if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"], $target_file)) {
     // do something when the file is uploaded
    } else {
       // do something when the file is not uploaded
    }
}
```

Your action can be empty to go to the same file or enter a filename where it needs to post to
**Your HTML**

```
<form method="post" action="thisfilename.php" enctype="multipart/form-data">
     <input type="file" name="image">
     <input type="submit" value="Submit" id="uploadimage">
 </form>
```